# How to disable row form elements present in second and third column using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to disable second row,third row,till nth row form elements which is present in second and third column using jquery selector.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr class="warning">
      <th>column1</th>
      <th>column2</th>
      <th>column3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>500.00</td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" id="ddcards">
          <option selected>Select Card</option>
          <option>CC0</option>
          <option>CC1</option>
          <option>CC2</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSubmit" value="submit">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>500.00</td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" id="ddcards">
          <option selected>Select Card</option>
          <option>CC0</option>
          <option>CC1</option>
          <option>CC2</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSubmit" value="submit">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>500.00</td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" id="ddcards">
          <option selected>Select Card</option>
          <option>CC0</option>
          <option>CC1</option>
          <option>CC2</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSubmit" value="submit">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Below is the sample screen [image]

Want to disable to row with the form elements which is present in the column
till nth row

one important condition like when button 1 clicked enable 2nd row,then when second button clicked enable third row...likewise it goes on

Comment: can you add your code in jsfiddle?

Comment: it'd be wiser to disable all, and then enable the first one

Comment: You cannot have duplicate `id` values in HTML.

Comment: here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/webdevanuj/45wd93r0/)

Comment: @trincot yeah it wont have duplicate just for demo i showed up!!!

Comment: @AnujKhandelwal yeah thanks man

Comment: @rselvaganesh glad to help :)

Comment: It seems overkill to ask the user to press submit on each row. The selection from the drop-down itself should be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use any of these

```
$("table tbody tr").slice(1).find('input,select').prop('disabled', true);
```

or

```
$("table tbody tr:not(:eq(0))").find('input,select').prop('disabled', true);
```

or

```
$("table tbody tr").gt(0).find('input,select').prop('disabled', true);
```

```js
$("table tbody tr").slice(1).find('input,select').prop('disabled', true);
$('input[type="submit"]').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parents('tr').next().find('input, select').prop('disabled', false);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr class="warning">
      <th>column1</th>
      <th>column2</th>
      <th>column3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>500.00</td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" id="ddcards">
          <option selected>Select Card</option>
          <option>CC0</option>
          <option>CC1</option>
          <option>CC2</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSubmit" value="submit">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>500.00</td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" id="ddcards">
          <option selected>Select Card</option>
          <option>CC0</option>
          <option>CC1</option>
          <option>CC2</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSubmit" value="submit">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>500.00</td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" id="ddcards">
          <option selected>Select Card</option>
          <option>CC0</option>
          <option>CC1</option>
          <option>CC2</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSubmit" value="submit">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>500.00</td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" id="ddcards">
          <option selected>Select Card</option>
          <option>CC0</option>
          <option>CC1</option>
          <option>CC2</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSubmit" value="submit">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>500.00</td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" id="ddcards">
          <option selected>Select Card</option>
          <option>CC0</option>
          <option>CC1</option>
          <option>CC2</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSubmit" value="submit">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>500.00</td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" id="ddcards">
          <option selected>Select Card</option>
          <option>CC0</option>
          <option>CC1</option>
          <option>CC2</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSubmit" value="submit">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: How will the user ever get to fill in the next row?

Comment: here one constrain once i click the submit button then next row should enable

Comment: @rselvaganesh possible. Let me make a fiddle.

Comment: @Prs one important condition like when button 1 clicked enable 2nd row,then when second button clicked enable third row...likewise it goes on

Comment: @Prs how to disable only drop down element of above row when button is clicked when ever I m moving forward to below rows

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$('.table > tbody tr:not(:first)').find('input,select,button').prop("disabled", true);
```

or better approach :

```
var leaveTr= '1';
$('.table > tbody tr').not(':eq('+leaveTr+')').find('input,select,button').prop("disabled", true);
```

```
$('.table > tbody tr').not(':eq(0)').find('input,select,button').prop("disabled", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want a form where only one row is available for the user to change an unselected value to a selected one. To achieve that I would suggest you would not disable the row controls, but hide the row completely until the user has selected a value in a row above it.

You also may want to deal with the situation where the user first fills in all rows, and then resets the selection on the first row. In that case it might be nice to move up all the selected values so that the unselected row comes after the other rows.

Finally, it does not really seem useful to have submit buttons on every row. The mere fact that the user makes a selection should be enough and trigger the next row to become visible. That is much more user-friendly.

Here is how you can achieve that:

```js
$(function() {
  function showRows() {
    // remove gaps
    $targetRows = $('.table-striped>tbody>tr');
    targetIndex = 0;
    $targetRows.each(function (index) {
      var $select = $(this).find('select.form-control');
      var selectedIndex = $select.prop('selectedIndex');
      if (targetIndex < index) {
        $targetRows.eq(targetIndex).find('select.form-control')
        .prop('selectedIndex', selectedIndex);
        $select.prop('selectedIndex', 0);
      }
      if (selectedIndex) targetIndex++;
    });
    targetIndex++;
    // show/hide rows, so only last one that is visible has unselected value
    $targetRows.slice(targetIndex).hide();
    $targetRows.slice(0,targetIndex).show();
  }

  $('.form-control').change(showRows);
  showRows();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr class="warning">
      <th>column1</th>
      <th>column2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>500.00</td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" name="ddcards">
          <option selected>Select Card</option>
          <option>CC0</option>
          <option>CC1</option>
          <option>CC2</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>500.00</td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" name="ddcards">
          <option selected>Select Card</option>
          <option>CC0</option>
          <option>CC1</option>
          <option>CC2</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>500.00</td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" name="ddcards">
          <option selected>Select Card</option>
          <option>CC0</option>
          <option>CC1</option>
          <option>CC2</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>500.00</td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" name="ddcards">
          <option selected>Select Card</option>
          <option>CC0</option>
          <option>CC1</option>
          <option>CC2</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

See how rows are made visible as soon as a value is selected, and how they are hidden again when a selection is undone, shifting the values up where needed.

Note that I replace the `id` properties by `name` properties to avoid `id` duplicates, which is not allowed in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below piece of `jquery code` will do the trick.

```
$("table tbody tr:not(:eq(0))").find("select,input").prop("disabled",true);
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/68q34vad/)**

Comment: it will work but only on the `form tags`, because you can't `disable` `tr` nor `td`. its a very simple solution with less piece of code and will disable all the `inputs, select` upto the nth `rows`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".table").each(function(){
    $(this).find('.form-control,.btn').prop('disabled',true);
    $(this).find('.form-control:first,.btn:first').prop('disabled',false);
});
});
```